# A name for something like a CW complex?

Tags: general-topology, notation

The class $\mathcal{CW}_n$ of finite $n$-dimensional CW complexes can be defined recursively:

- $\mathcal{CW}_0$ consists of finite sets;
- If $X \in \mathcal{CW}_n$, $\phi:S^n \amalg \cdots \amalg S^n \to X$ is continuous, then the pushforward $Y$ in
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  S^n\amalg \cdots \amalg S^n & \to & X \\
  \downarrow&& \downarrow \\
  D^{n+1}\amalg \cdots\amalg D^{n+1} & \to & Y
  \end{array}
  is in $\mathcal{CW}_{n+1}$.

i.e. $n$-dimensional CW complexes are built by recursively gluing $n$-dimensional cells onto $(n-1)$-dimensional skeletons.
My question is whether there is a name for spaces achieved by the same construction, except that $n$-dimensional cells may be glued onto skeletons of any dimension.

To be precise, let $\mathcal A$ be the smallest class such that:

- $\mathcal A$ contains finite sets, and
- If $X \in \mathcal{A}$, $\phi:S^n \amalg \cdots \amalg S^n \to X$ is continuous, then the pushforward $Y$ in
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  S^n\amalg \cdots \amalg S^n & \to & X \\
  \downarrow&& \downarrow \\
  D^{n+1}\amalg \cdots\amalg D^{n+1} & \to & Y
  \end{array}
  is in $\mathcal{A}$.

Question: does the class $\mathcal A$ have a name?

Background: These spaces might not be useful for anything, but I have a related noncommutative construction and I'm looking for a name to give it, which could be inspired by the name for $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Sorry, what does the superscript $m$ denote?
Also, are you sure that the elements of $\mathcal{CW}_n$ are simply finite sets?

Comment: I am guessing that your notation $(S^n)^m$ means the disjoint union of $m$ copies of $S^n$, but if so then writing $m$ as an exponent is not what you want.

Comment: I'm confused, we are already allowed to glue $n$-cells onto the skeleton of dimension less than $n-1$, consider the usual cell structure of the $2$-sphere for instance which has a single $0$-cell and a single $2$-cell.

Comment: Mosher and Berci: Thanks for pointing out these mistakes, they are now fixed.

Comment: These are cell complexes in the sense of model category theory.

Comment: Zhen: Could you give me a reference for where "cell complex" is used in this sense (ideally, a textbook rather than a paper)? From what I can tell, "cell complex" often means something like CW complex, where you can only glue n-cells to $(n-1)$-skeletons.

Comment: Daniel, you're right (and I've corrected the question). But the issue is about being allowed to glue $n$-cells to a skeleton of dimension $\geq n$.

Comment: See any textbook that discusses the small object argument, or ideally, cofibrantly generated model categories. For instance, Hovey [1999] or Hirschhorn [2003]. Alternatively, look at §0.5 of [my notes](http://zll22.user.srcf.net/writing/homotopical-algebra/2014-05-09-Main.pdf).